# WebStorm/PhpStorm and JavaScript ES6: destructuring assignment not recognized

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phpstorm, webstorm

Consider this ES6 code:

```
class Person {
    constructor(first, last) {
        let fixed = this.normalize(first, last);
        this.first = fixed[0];
        this.last = fixed[1];
    }

    normalize(first, last) {
        return [first.toUpperCase(), last.toUpperCase()];
    }
}
```

PhpStorm/WebStorm has no problem recognizing that `first` and `last` are properties of the class when I later use them:

[image]

Now if I modify the constructor to use the [destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
constructor(first, last) {
    [this.first, this.last] = this.normalize(first, last);
}
```

The code executes without error, but the IDE can no longer see the properties:

[image]

[image]

Is this a problem with my code? My IDE settings? I use `PhpStorm 2017.2.4`

Comment: *"Is this a problem with my code?'* No, your code is fine. Apparently PhpStorm 2017.2.4 just doesn't understand destructuring assignment in the constructor (yet).

Answer (score 2):

You can manually tell PHPStorm that these properties should be assumed to exist on `Person`-linked objects by adding a JSDoc to the class:

```
/**
 * @property {String} first
 * @property {String} last
 */
class Person {
    // ...
}
```